# Java 8 Stream: Extract map from list of objects and sum specific key

Tags: java, java-8, java-stream

I have a list of `Customer` objects

```
class Customer {
     //Other properties
     Map<String, Object> additionalData;
}
```

When I got a `List<Customer> customers`, I want to sum a key called `transactions` in `additionalData`. How can I do that with java 8 streams?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can map each element of your list to the value of the "transactions" key in the corresponding map, and then sum these values:

```
int sum = customers.stream()
                   .map(c->(Integer)c.additionalData.get("transactions"))
                   .filter(Objects::nonNull)
                   .mapToInt (Integer::intValue)
                   .sum();
```

For example:

```
Customer c1 = new Customer();
c1.additionalData = new LinkedHashMap<> ();
c1.additionalData.put ("transactions", 14);
Customer c2 = new Customer();
c2.additionalData = new LinkedHashMap<> ();
c2.additionalData.put ("transactions", 7);
Customer c3 = new Customer();
c3.additionalData = new LinkedHashMap<> ();
List<Customer> customers = Arrays.asList (c1,c2,c3);
int sum = customers.stream()
                   .map(c->(Integer)c.additionalData.get("transactions"))
                   .filter(Objects::nonNull)
                   .mapToInt (Integer::intValue)
                   .sum();
System.out.println ("sum is " + sum);
```

Output:

```
sum is 21
```

This code is assuming the `additionalData` member is never `null`, and the value of the `"transactions"` key (if it exists in the `Map`) is always an `Integer`. If these assumptions are incorrect, the code should be adjusted accordingly.

Comment: Thanks @Eran. In some cases additionalData is null and "transactions" key is sometimes "Double" (only in historic records). I altered code accordingly.

Comment: It would be better if you filter first and then get the value: `customers.stream().filter(c -> c.additionalData.containsKey("transactions")).mapToInt(c -> (int) c.additionalData.get("transactions")).sum();`.

Comment: Thanks @Flown. Updated to

customers.stream()
                        .map(Customer::getAdditionalData)
                        .filter(Objects::nonNull)
                        .filter(additionalData -> additionalData.containsKey("transactions"))
                        .filter(additionalData -> additionalData.get("transactions") instanceof Integer)
                        .map(additionalData -> (Integer) additionalData.get("transactions"))
                        .filter(Objects::nonNull)
                        .mapToInt(Integer::intValue).sum();

Comment: You don't need the last `.filter(Objects::nonNull)` because `null instanceof Integer` evaluates to `false`.